# Power Supply wiring check

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, 12v

I'm not too confident with electronics and I'm currently working on a project where I need a 12V mains power supply. I got a switch for it and have wired it. I've shown pictures.

Is this wiring correct? I'm confident it is, but need someone to check.

Thanks

[image: photo showing rear of switch and wiring]

[image: photo showing front of switch and wiring][image]

Comment: What does datasheet show?

Comment: Please show us the datasheet for the power entrance module.

Comment: Didn't get one unfortunately. Neither on the supply or switch. I follow3d a YouTube tutorial this far but I wanted a second opinion

Comment: I'll mention (in case it isn't obvious) that this setup is *highly* dangerous if used outside of a suitable enclosure, due to the exposed mains voltage on the rear of that power entry connector / module and on the power supply. Also, just FYI, I was taught to also crimp the insulation on spade terminals around the wire, to act as strain relief.

Comment: Use a multimeter or reference document to determine which pins go the the indicator light, which to each side of the switch, and which to each of the pins in the receptacle.  It's not clear from your pictures.  Tell us this and we can give you a good answer, tell us what you're planning to mount this inside of and we can probably give you a good idea of how to make sure it's safe.

Comment: it looks credible, but I can't say fire sure that it's correct, often illuminated switches have separate terminals for the illumination, and the illumination voltage may not be the same as mains voltage....  maybe you have a single pole switch there.

Comment: I'll try find a document on the web for it. And I was planning on 3d printing an enclosure. Would that be safe? How are these supply usually made safe?

Comment: Do you have anything at all that you can use to do a continuity test? a aa battery, resistor and an led would be sufficient.  Or are there markings in the plastic that aren't clear in the picture?
Some things you can do to make it safer:  Start with where the electricity enters the device:  Any metal part of the device of substantial size that is not intended to carry current should be connected to the ground terminal.  Parts should be mounted securely to the enclosure, which should be physically robust enough for the intended use, or plausible calamity (like being dropped while plugged in).

Comment: Make sure that you allow for adequate airflow.  That power supply is vented for a reason.  If it has a fan in it, you can combine whatever vents you put into your design with its existing design.  Be sure all wires are adequately sized.  Double or triple insulate.  If you're not running the device at it's full capacity, feel free to throw in an extra fuse to protect your little PSU.  Label the device externally for it's maximum wattage and connect it with adequately sized cord.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I checked online for a wiring diagram and have added it to the images. I was intending to print an enclosure to slide over and would have hole vents like the case although heating shouldnt be an issue as I will be drawing like 5A (3 steppers plus arduino) and it's rated for 15A. Regarding the extra fuse there is one in the switch. I'm planning on using a 1A or 2A fuse in the switch. I'm in the UK so 220V mains. This should be okay right. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have wired it correctly.

[image]

If the switch indicator lamp stays on independently of switch position then swap the input and output wires on the switch.

Comment: Could you, please, clarify this: "If the lamp stays on independently of switch position then swap the input and output wires on the switch." Because I don't see how it is possible and what swapping wires could achieve.

Comment: As shown on my overlay the indicator lamp is on the "lower" side of the switch. If you want the lamp to switch on and off with the load then the load should be wired to the lower terminals and mains to the other pair. If you swap the wires from the top to the bottom terminals the indicator will be powered all the time regardless of the switch position. Does that make sense?

Comment: Oops.. brain fart, sorry. I thought you meant connecting external lamp to those terminals to check if switch is wired properly.

Comment: Oh this would explain why I find 2 different wiring diagrams when I search Google. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: OK. If that completely answers your question then please accept the answer to mark it solved. Otherwise wait a couple of days to encourage other answers and choose the best if you are completely satisfied. You can upvote as many as you think are helpful.